# I have a real question that I think would be useful, but it is getting down voted. How do I fix it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I read the criteria for on-topic questions and it included the following:

> practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development

I also have what I believe to be a legitimate, serious question that meets this criteria for anyone writing and publishing a C++ library:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302730/creating-an-effective-c-library-website-and-documentation

I read the help center and it seems to meet all the criteria. While at a quick glance this may look like it belongs on server fault, it really doesn't because it is specifically about how to give library users a good learning and programming experience with a C++ library. It is not "how to set up a website", or anything like that. It is also not a purely subjective question.

Unfortunately, as soon as I posted it it started getting down voted so I delete it. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix the question so that people are happy with it?

The question for those < 10k:

> #### Creating an effective C++ library website and documentation
>
> Creating a C++ library also means documenting it so that others can
>   use it, and that documentation can vary dramatically in quality.
>
> **How should a website for a C++ library be structured so that it is most effective, and are there any pearls that can be held up as
>   quality examples?**
>
> To frame the question, I think there are three groups that it is most
>   important for a library website and documentation to cater to:
>
> 1. New users need an excellent, easy introduction, download, setup, and documentation that clearly flows from one step to the next.
> 2. Seasoned users need a solid reference with fast access to the details they need, and clear information about new updates.
> 3. New contributors need a how to guide covering the steps they must take to get their contributions into the library.
>
> I would like to figure out how to make each very happy with what they
>   see and use.

Comment: The question is... well... a bit too broad..

Comment: Since @Martijn was kind enough to edit a copy in the post.... here's my feedback.... unfortunately it is off-topic. It is way too broad, and very subjective.

Comment: The problem is that the question is opinion based.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks! I didn't know that. I reopened it for now. How long before the negative reputation takes effect? I want to ask a good question so I figured if there was a clear way to rewrite it I would do so, but my search for how to improve it using the explanation of how to use stackoverflow didn't address my meta-question.

Comment: @AndrewHundt it takes effect right away, but deleting restores it.  But do that too much, or have too many negative posts and you could end up question banned so don't delete too much.

Comment: @Linuxious general user experience design principles have been thoroughly researched and there are proven and citable ways to have designs that are objectively better at engaging an audience. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience I would think that software programmers are simply a more specific audience, so while the question may sound subjective at first glance, I don't think it is.

Comment: Maybe, but this question isn't really about programming, is it?

Comment: If you can edit your question to explain what "most effective" means to you, I'll migrate it to our User Experience site, or to Programmers

Comment: Although the question is on hold, it has not yet been deleted - everyone can still see it, including those under 10K! Although, including it in your question helps keep it handy, just in case it is deleted at some point.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it was very nice of you to migrate it with [shopping request included](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/214082/revisions "'are there any pearls that can be held up as quality examples'")

Comment: @gnat: We aim to please.

Comment: If only there was a site on the SE network, where you could ask questions like "how can I improve this question before posting on StackOverflow" (or whatever other site you want to post on - maybe you could even ask which site is most appropriate)...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The main problem that the question has is that we don't know what "most effective" means to you. Programming is always a series of tradeoffs; there's no such thing as the "optimal" program, library or website. There is only that which is optimal for your particular use case.

In addition, "are there any pearls that can be held up as quality examples" is asking for recommendations; we have a "close reason", or reason for questions to be closed, specifically devoted to that. Look for library websites that have documentation you like, and model theirs.

Finally, pay closer attention to the Help Center, which states that "some questions are off-topic, *even if they meet one of the criteria listed above."* (including "practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development").

Comment: The question sort of belongs between the user experience stack exchange and the programming one, which is unfortunate. I think the programming one could result in better answers. You are right that there isn't a definitive "optimal" due to shades of grey, there are cases that can be definitively measured as "better" and "worse".

Comment: What did you mean by "In addition, asking for "pearls" is a shopping exercise; we have a close reason specifically devoted to that."? Could you clarify?

Comment: @AndrewHundt Looks like your question has been migrated to Programmers.

Comment: It's in the help center article that you read.  The close reason says: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: Statements like "*asking for "pearls" is a shopping exercise*" are very much Meta SO jargon (in my opinion, at least).  People that spend a lot of time on Meta / reading the blogs get it, but I imagine most people would not.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Alright, I'll modify the answer a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks, Robert.  I think this is a excellent answer, and rather helpful, by the way.  I do think it's clearer now.  My comment was more general, in that I think Meta regulars do that frequently - use jargon familiar to us, without considering the "audience" (the OP).  I imagine a lot of question-askers here haven't read "Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping" or "Optimizing for Pearls, Not Sand" or whatever they're called.

Comment: But there is a problem with the community. Sometimes the question is very good, but a certain person does not understand and downvote it. Take a look in my answer. It got downvoted for no reason.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256989/use-return-value-of-a-function/19257170#19257170

Comment: @MauricioAbreu: I made some observations in a comment below your answer.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but in my honest opinion all my downvotes are given for lazy people. Some people need to find out what is not working and just give the code is not a good way to teach what is really happening. It is like when in Math you just give the final answer: you learn nothing.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I edited my question giving a better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between a "programming question" and a "question a programmer might have."

Your question is not resolvable using programming.  You are a programmer, and it is a question you'd like to solve, but it's not a programming question.